# Как разбить файловый путь и получить последний элемент?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь получить файловый путь в php7:

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\\,]+/", dirname($filename));
```

Как получить последний элемент если строка:

```
upload/iblock/faa/file.jpg
```

Comment: последний элемент это `faa`? то есть вы в функцию то передаете без имени файла.

Comment: Да, я передаю dirname($filename)

Comment: [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php), [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php).

Comment: И надо получить последний элемент path

Comment: Что подразумевается под последним элементом?
Вообще для работы с путями файлов есть pathinfo http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: `ck\/(\w+)\/` - вот рабатоющий рег-экс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения последней секции строк пути с помощью регулярных выражений вы можете использовать, например, следующий вариант: `([\w\s]+)\/?$`. Последний слэш опциональный. В `\w\s` попадают символы `A-Za-z0-9_` и пробел. Можно дополнить, добавив туда, например, `А-Яа-я-`, и т.п.

```
preg_match("/([\w\s]+)\/?$/", "/upload/iblock/faa/", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

В первой группе будет искомая строка:

```
Array (
    [0] => faa/
    [1] => faa
)
```

*В целом, зная о функции `dirname()`, которую вы используете в своем коде, вы, наверное, также знаете и о функции [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php), возвращающей как раз последний элемент пути, а так же [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php), [`SplFileInfo::getFilename`](http://php.net/manual/ru/splfileinfo.getfilename.php). Для получения пути можно даже разбить его с помощью [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) и достать последний элемент, используя [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php). Поэтому если ваша задача - работать с путями, а не тренировать регулярные выражения, то используете соответствующие функции.*